# Symfony DomCrawler. Filter condition

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

I have this script in Symfony 2:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class MyController extends Controller
{
....
foreach($crawler->filter('[type="text/css"]') as $content){
/* make things */
}
foreach($crawler->filter('[rel="stylesheet"]') as $content){
/* make things */
}
```

¿can `$crawler->filter` accept various conditions and do it in one foreach? For example:

```
foreach($crawler->filter('[rel="stylesheet"] OR [type="text/css"]') as $content){
/* make things */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter function takes a standard CSS selector, so:

```
foreach ($crawler->filter('[rel="stylesheet"],[type="text/css"]') as $content) {
   /* make things */
}
```

Should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible but you can do this:

```
$crawler->filter('[rel="stylesheet"]')->addAll($crawler->filter('[type="text/css"]'));
```

This should resolve your problem.

Additionaly, you can also filter with xpath.